# Is it okay to repost outdated or obsolete questions?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

*Not a duplicate. I'm asking about old version-dependent **questions.***

Is it okay to ask questions that have already been asked (and answered), but are obsolete? Like, if there's an old question that asks for debugging with an outdated version of a framework, and in the latest version things have changed quite a bit? Will it be marked as a duplicate if I repost it?

Comment: Be sure to mention the possible duplicate in your new question and explain in detail why it doesn't work for you (anymore).

Comment: to add to what @πάνταῥεῖ said you would need to show what you have also tried (you version with the updated famework that's not working), otherwise you'd have people reposting `mysql_` questions just because they can no longer use it in the latest version of PHP and want to use `mysqli_` or `PDO`

Comment: I would recommend posting a bounty on the existing question instead.

Comment: I think a new question is better than bounty, a new question can describe a question in more restrict and specific way, where just a bounty doesn't tell others what you need, and a new question may help future visitors which suffers from the same problem that previous answers don't work

Comment: If you *know* that your post is good, then I suggest to not delete it, even if it was voted down. The site requires a more diverse spectrum of opinions, and if a clearly okay post was voted down into oblivion, it says more from the voters as from the post. Don't worry - there are clear guidelines what is accepted here and what is not. Posting something which is disagreed by the community is obviously acceptable. *You are allowed to express your opinion, even if it will be downvoted.*

Comment: I think, not this is the reason, why it is not a dupe, as you state. I think it is not a dupe because you are asking for re-asking a new question about the new version. I think it wouldn't be a bad idea (for example, having different questions for android studio 0.1, 0.5 and 1.0), and cross-linking them in comments. I think it would be better as the current practice (handling all the versions in a single question where the most upvoted answer is obsolete).

Answer (score 6):

**If you *know* the answer, then you should (generally) post it to the existing question.** For example, if there's an old question about how to do *x* in the kQuery framework, and all the answers are talking about doing it in kQuery 1.0, but there's now a better way to do it in kQuery 2.0, you should post an answer that (A) explains why the new way is better, and (B) shows an example of how it works. Be sure to mention explicitly that it only works in kQuery 2.0, not on older versions.

This is good because it keeps as much of the information as possible in a single place. Your new answer will gradually increase in score over time, and hopefully eventually be at the top of the list. Who knows, if the person who originally asked the question is around, they might even change and accept it. I've seen this happen before several times. If not, oh well. It's not all about earning rep.

**On the other hand, if you *don't* know the answer,** you just know that the answers given to an existing question don't work for you on a newer version, then I believe **you should ask a new question.** As has been suggested, your new question should make reference to the original question, explain why those answers don't work for you, and say that you're looking for a solution compatible with kQuery 2.0 (and don't care about kQuery 1.0 compatibility).

I would caution strongly against posting a bounty on the existing (old) question, as Tiny Giant suggested. Why? Because the bounty is effectively changing the question. From the outset, all of the existing answers are ineligible for the bounty because they do not answer your slightly modified question. Worse, the situation is very confusing for all who happen upon the question because of your bounty because the question itself is subtly different from the question being asked in the bounty box. I've seen users try and do this, and it just doesn't work. So please don't do it. If your question differs in any way, even subtly, from the existing question, don't bounty the existing question—ask a new one.

The system is perfectly capable of handling additional questions. Duplicates are only a problem if they rehash and scatter information that is already available elsewhere. By definition, in your scenario, the information is not available in the other question. As long as you make clear from the outset, in the question itself, why your question is not a duplicate, this should prevent it from being closed as one.

Comment: But what if you first think to get the answer from an accepted answer, and that turns out to be a wrong solution? See [Would a new question on how to update Anaconda be in line with the community if there is already a similar but messy and old 500k views question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/411294/would-a-new-question-on-how-to-update-anaconda-be-in-line-with-the-community-if). Such questions offer the right answer, but few will find it, which should give way to open a new question instead.