# Would a new question on how to update Anaconda be in line with the community if there is already a similar but messy and old 500k views question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I hope this is not a duplicate of [Is it okay to repost outdated or obsolete questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333443/is-it-okay-to-repost-outdated-or-obsolete-questions) which does not deal with this strange case of a totally misleading and accepted answer which is by far the strongest in votes and appearance.

Quoting the comment there:

> But what if you first think to get the answer from an accepted answer,
> and that turns out to be a wrong solution? See [Would a new question
> on how to update Anaconda be in line with the community if there is
> already a similar but messy and old 500k views
> question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/411294/would-a-new-question-on-how-to-update-anaconda-be-in-line-with-the-community-if). Such questions offer the right answer, but few will find it, which
> should give way to open a new question instead.

---

There is an existing question with 500k views, [How do I update Anaconda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45197777/how-do-i-update-anaconda). Thinking about a new question, before I catch a lot of downvotes and the question gets closed as a duplicate, I better check whether such a new question would be backed up by the community.

The new question would be as follows (with the spin-off as the question to be replaced):

---

Question Title:

> Windows: In 09/2021, How do I update Anaconda in Anaconda Prompt command line to get the most recent stable collection of packages?

Question body:

> This is a Spin-off from [How do I update
> Anaconda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45197777/how-do-i-update-anaconda)
> which is a mess. The highly accepted answer leads with the claim to
> show what 95 % of the people want, although the offered solution can
> lead to unstable environment. There are partly contradicting comments
> and advices and the right answers are probably not clear enough. There
> were meta discussions in the past that came to the conclusion that
> such questions should be closed and asked again.
>
> Therefore the same question again.
>
> Setting:
>
> - 05.09.2021
> - Windows 10
> - Anaconda
> - base environment
> - some virtual environments
>
> In Administrator mode of the Anaconda prompt and searching only for a
> command line solution:
>
> How do I update the whole Anaconda so that I get a **stable** and in
> these contraints **most recent** setting of packages for the exact date of 05.09.2021? I try to reach
> this in all of my environments (base and virtual). My aim is to get one clear command line example for the given date which then can serve as an example for the future.

---

I am not sure whether it helps to add a Windows setting, I can take that out, since the way to update should be the same on Linux. On the other hand, you can choose OS + Anaconda version at the official docs' [available Anaconda versions](https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/) *(which is, funny enough, not sorted by date)*, and then, a precise example for the Windows case should be even better. Therefore my guess is that choosing Windows will help solving the same on Linux, but choosing no OS will just make the question vague.

The solution to the question is already in the the docs: [Updating from older versions](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/update-version/). Yet, many people will not look up the docs but take the first hit of Stack Overflow instead, to find the question (07/2017) being upvoted 308 times, the accepted answer (07/2017) being upvoted 483 times, and the [right answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58885970/11154841) (11/2019) being upvoted just 30 times. I myself have upvoted the wrong, but accepted answer. You believe it at first sight, I did not expect to search for the right metapackage when I just want to have the most recent Anaconda installer, the `--all` was much more appealing. I also did not expect the "30 votes answer" to be up-to-date, who should expect a solution that uses a `05/2021` command to be the most recent metapackage install on 05.09.2021?

Do you support opening the quoted new question? And if so, is there any change needed to avoid downvotes and closing?

Comment: If you ask a new question, search engines will still generally direct people to the old one so all you'll achieve is extra clutter. Upvote useful answer(s), downvote bad ones, add a comment indicating flaws in bad answers if you want but you can't fix things all on your own here. If lots more people agree with you then *eventually* the answer scores should reflect that.

Comment: @RobertLongson The accepted answer is wrong. Your last sentence does not seem to work. There are enough comments and answers that say that the answer is wrong. The voting is biased by the appearance of the accepted answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it okay to repost outdated or obsolete questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333443/is-it-okay-to-repost-outdated-or-obsolete-questions)

Comment: Regarding your proposed title: please do not add tags as prefixes to the title. Use the appropriate keywords naturally in the title. E.g. "on Windows version XY".

Comment: It looks like you [like to post  "this is a spin-off" kinda questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A11154841+%22this+is+a+spin+off%22). Personally, I don't think they've succeeded too much at being particularly useful concept. We do not do "spin-offs" here. Either a question is a duplicate, or stands on its own. You can link to other posts as secondary supporting material or as to demonstrate research, but I don't think the concept of "question forks" or "spin-offs" as such makes much sense.

Comment: @RobertLongson That alleged duplicate of the meta question here does not solve a problem that is caused by the search engines: The accepted answer gets upvoted more than you can expect downvotes from "professionals" to balance this out. And there are already comments under the wrong and accepted answer saying that the answer is unstable. Many people just read the answer, not the comments.

Comment: @questionto42: Is there anything that your question would cover that is not covered by the other answers on the old post? There are more than 10 other answers (some of them heavily upvoted), does non of them answer your question?

Comment: @BDL You have not read the question here thoroughly enough. In this meta question here, I give you the right answer from that list of answers, and I mention the caveat that this right answer shows how it got the release, but does not refer to the version list. Upvoted 30 times against 483.

Comment: @questionto42: In this case I'd suggest that you edit the answer that is already there with the missing information. If you ask a question that is (badly) answered by some other post it is very likely that it will be closed as duplicate.

Comment: @BDL My comment was not about improving any answer there. It is more about showing that the 500k viewers were not able to give the right answer in 2.5 years, and then the right answer did not even take up the guideline of the official update docs, but searched for the latest release notes site. This meta question is (also) about this systemic problem that is revealed here. If I downvoted and changed things, it would make a small step, but I found out about the things I could change because I opened this meta question and then read into it. No one will do this, normally.

Comment: On the face of it you're saying that 483 people are wrong and that you (and maybe 30 others) are right and that you should have more power than 483 other people because you're right and they are wrong. Voting is how we judge things here so sometimes it's true that you might feel like a small cog. Really it's best to move on and hope that time fixes it as others upvote the answer you think is correct and downvote the one you think is wrong.

Comment: Forget about it, Anaconda itself is a mess.

Comment: @RobertLongson I have upvoted the accepted question and I will downvote it only now, after dealing with this for an hour. Downvoting is not that wide-spread in such high-voted questions anyway, because everyone knows that paying 1 rep is not worth it on a 4 year-old answer. I am a good example to show that the voting does not work as I also fell for the seemingly nice solution of the accepted answer myself.

Comment: *Everyone* knows? I certainly try to downvote bad answers when I come across them.

Comment: There are more answers on the duplicate than just the accepted one. Are all the others also wrong? How would a new answer to your new question be identified as more correct than the old answer to the old question?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Please read the question and comments more thoroughly. I have already put the answer that is "right" at the bottom, and a comment like yours was already discussed before. By the way, I had to edit the "right answer" since it uses `install` instead of `update` in its commands, and it does not explain enough. Not sure whether the edit will be accepted, though.

Comment: @RobertLongson OK, I downvoted it now as well but my last vote is locked in. Not possible for now.

Comment: @questionto42 It's hard to extract that from the question (where this information should be – not in the comments). If you are now claiming the "right answer" *wasn't actually right* but had to be edited, that is even more confusing. Regardless of whether the *first part* of my comment is covered by what is there already, the most important part is actually the *second part*: How does adding another *disjoint* Q&A improve the situation? Mind that you yourself have admitted not actually to have bothered verifying what is correct before voting. How would a second, low-voted Q&A win?

Comment: On an unrelated note, what is the advantage of the proposed new question basically trash-talking the old one?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi This meta Q shows the right answer at the bottom which needs to be edited. That is a messy situation, yes. It is still clear that you have not really read it. And also, you say that it was not in the comments, then just search for the comment of BDL. And the other part: Do you really believe that this wrong answer will be upvoted again like this if it is clearly commented and voted that it is just wrong from the start? I can add the "right" answer to it at point 0 as well, not just 2.5 years later. The right answer would hopefully win this race, sure is nothing.

Comment: "you say that it was not in the comments" I did no such thing. "it is still clear that you have not really read it" Please refrain from assuming what I did nor did not do. That is not productive.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi It is not productive if two people in these comments ask me whether an answer might not already be right there although that is covered by the question here, and then even get upvoted, see BDL.

Comment: "…if it is clearly commented and voted that it is just wrong from the start" I believe that the comment – as proposed now – will be swiftly edited out and likely even flagged. Unilaterally talking down on the content of other Q&A is not the purpose of questions. Such meta-commentary is of no use to readers viewing the question in isolation and usually removed quickly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236780/discussion-between-mistermiyagi-and-questionto42).

Comment: The very [resource that this meta-question refers to](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/update-version/) in order to claim the accepted answer is wrong conflicts with the [changes proposed by the OP to the "right answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/29746426). Can someone else please confirm which content is actually wrong?

Comment: What would happen if someone posts an answer to your new question with the allegedly incorrect approach and this answer will get much more upvotes than your answer?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi The edit was rejected because I have, among other things, changed the `install` to `update` (which was really wrong, sorry for that, `install` is the official code, I have overseen that since I did expect an `update`), but that was just a tiny part of the edit. The main intention was to show how you get that 2021.05 version not just from the release page, but also from the versions list, since only the latter is mentioned in the official docs.

Comment: I see now that the official docs also stick to the release version scheme like `2021.05` (or in the example, `conda update anaconda=2019.10`. Thus, my whole edit was not needed, instead, the answer seems to be fully correct and the edit was rejected rightly. This is a bit embarassing for me, sorry to have overseen this. Yet, it also makes it easier again to say that the question there has a "right answer", but the votes do not show this to the reader, especially not at first sight. I added a comment instead of the edit.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I would comment and downvote this and ask others to do the same. It would likely develop differently since what we see in the older question is just a product of long time ago. The official docs say: `conda update --all may not be able to make everything the latest versions because you may have conflicting constraints in your environment.` This will likely not be upvoted as much as we see it there. If it still develops in the wrong direction, there is nothing to do about it but to leave it as such, but it should be given a try.

Comment: “The accepted answer is wrong. Your last sentence does not seem to work.” - So? Does that stop you from submitting a answer that is correct? Lots of questions have the incorrect answer accepted.

Comment: @SecurityHound I took the time and added an answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Basically, you want to post a duplicate question, that's already answered (correctly and incorrectly, per your summary) in the question you are duplicating.

> the accepted answer (07/2017) being upvoted 483 times, and the [right answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58885970/11154841) (11/2019) being upvoted just 30 times.

Since the answer to the question you propose to post already exists under a different question, it's a textbook duplicate.

Even if the “right” answer didn’t exist there, it’s still a dupe. It would just mean one need to add “the right answer” or comment/edit to help improve the existing answers.

Nothing guarantees in any way that posting a duplicate question duplicating the "right" answer of the duplicate would help with the discoverability problems you say exist.

Look for other ways of helping here. Posting a duplicate question is not it.

Comment: The idea would then be to open a new one and make the old one the duplicate of the new one. I have seen this practice on meta discussions earlier on, it was discussed by a gold user of a tag who said that he does so frequently. I cannot find the link to this anymore. I am not a gold user, but this is about a systematic problem of quick search engine votes against slower downvotes and a vague question (it does not say which OS nor whether it wants a command line or a GUI solution).